# Text Copying from Power BI Report Card Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to allow people I share my reports to be able to copy some text that is put in a "card" visual. I tried to select different custom online visuals but I could not get this done.

In the example below, I want the text "25 September - 01 October, 2019" to be copied (CTRL+C). Is there any possible way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTRL+C would only work in slicer. However, you can copy values from table and or matrix visual. Maybe you can use the date value in table or matrix increase the font size, change background colour etc so that it eventually looks like a card...

Answer (score 1):

You were probably hoping for some way in which users could select the text, as if it was a textbox, and then simply hit CTRL+C to copy it into the clipboard. Unfortunately, that is not possible with any of the standard visuals in Power BI. Instead, your users would have to click the ellipsis button on the visual and choose "Export data", which produces a CSV file with the value(s) in the visual.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is the current way of doing it. However, it is not a good solution if the receiver will have to do this step several times a week while a CRTL+C could be an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

If they are windows users (which they probably are because they use PowerBI) then snipping tool (built into windows) has a 'text options' that will copy the text using OCR.

[image: Snipping tool text options]